# Non-parametric test for separating samples from two populations

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, computational-statistics, finite-population

I have samples $\mathcal{Z} = \{Z_1,\ldots,Z_n\}$. These samples either come from the unknown distribution $\mathcal{D}_1$ or $\mathcal{D}_2$. (**Note**: I can't make any assumptions about these distributions). I wish to devise a non-parametric test for identifying and picking a maximal subset, $\mathcal{S} \subset \mathcal{Z}$ of samples all of which come from $\mathcal{D}_1$ (or alternatively $\mathcal{D}_2$).

If I am to do this naively by checking for all possible subsets, it's going to be computationally expensive. Is there a clever way to do this?

Is there any literature that has looked into such subset selection problems? Or are there any suggestions to formulate the problem differently?

**Clarification: I am not looking for a numerical solution. I am looking for ways to formally state and prove such statements.**

Comment: is cluster analysis of any help?

Comment: Hi, I am looking to formally state and prove such statements. Could you elaborate on your comment?

Comment: see, e.g. http://sherrytowers.com/2013/10/24/k-means-clustering/

Comment: @utobi Hi, I am aware of clustering-based tools to do such things numerically. But I am not looking for numerical solutions to my question. I wish to mathematically formulate and prove what I have asked in my question. Please let me know if you have any thoughts on that.

Comment: can you explain what, if any, is the statistical motivation behind this?

Comment: Perhaps you may get some useful feedback from this https://doi.org/10.1080/03610929008830345